# How to retrieve data from R console into a CSV file without suppressing the rows and columns

Tags: r, export-to-csv, igraph

I have a large adjacency matrix from igraph package with dimension 25074*25074 in R console. I'm trying to extract the R console result into a CSV file. But then I could only view the suppressed version of the file in CSV as well.

Comment: What kind of result do you want to extract? Can you provide snippet of the data?

Comment: Write.csv usually works. But please clarify more

Comment: I tried using the write.csv (write.csv(weightmatrix,file="matrix.csv")) but as the data being very large I'm getting an Error stating: 
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]],optional=True):cannot coerce class "structure("dgCMatrix",package="Matrix")" to a data.frame

Comment: That's not the problem. Try cohercing your "dgCMatrix" to a matrix with write.csv(as.matrix(weightmatrix),file="matrix.csv")

Comment: I tried converting into matrix using as.matrix but then its giving me an error stating:
Error in asMethod(Object) : Cholomod error: 'problem too large' at file ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're likely trying to write a "dgCMatrix" class object to a csv. Try:

```
# Generate random graph
gr <- erdos.renyi.game(10,1/10)

# Create adjacency matrix
ad <- as_adjacency_matrix(gr)

# You can't export this as a csv, because write.csv prefers a matrix or df, and
class(ad)
# [1] "dgCMatrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Matrix"

# Convert to matrix
ad <- as.matrix(ad)

#Save
write.csv(ad, "adjacency.csv")
```

Comment: But here I'm not able to convert into a matrix due to memory constraint

Comment: OK, so the problem is in converting to a matrix. Do you need to write the adjacency matrix to a csv? Can you just save the RData file: save.image(file = "temp.RData)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the RData file. but still, it gives me the compressed data. The problem is how do I get the whole adjacency matrix without the rows and columns being suppressed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve. You want your 25074*25074 matrix to be printed in the console?

Comment: I want the 25074*25074 matrix to be printed such that I get the uncompressed data.

Comment: The data are not compressed: they are just trimmed when printed. You can change global settings `options(max.print = 26000)` or use `utils::View(ad)`. It seems like you don't understand how R stores and displays data. You can check [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Introduction) for general reference.